# Derived Subgroup Criteria

Tags: group-theory

So I have been self studying abstract algebra and I have run into a strange condition when playing around with some finite groups and I was wondering if this situation could ever occur. It is:

Let G be a finite group where G=G'H and G' and H have co-prime order in which both are abelian. I have shown that G'=[G',H] (This is a problem in Issac's Finite group theory) , since G is product of two abelian subgroups.

I was wondering if this situation could ever actually occur. The situation that G'=[G',H] seems strange to me and I am sure it can not but I can seem to find a valid reason.

Comment: I mean that the derived subgroup of G, which is G', is equal to the commutator of the two subgroups G' and H.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this occurs for $G = S_3$, the symmetric group of degree $3$.  The derived subgroup is $\langle (1,2,3)\rangle$, and take $H=\langle (1,2)\rangle$.  Here, $G^\prime$ has order $3$ and $H$ has order $2$.

Comment: Ah, such a small example. I should have immediately checked GAP. Thanks.